# Expressjs not recognizing static files

Tags: node.js, express

I have a nodejs app and am using expressjs. I've defined my static directory, but when I access it, it doesn't load.  My express config is:

```
var app = express.createServer().listen(8001);
app.configure(function(){
      app.use(express.methodOverride());
      app.use(express.bodyParser());
      app.use(app.router);
      app.use('/public', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
      app.use(express.cookieParser());
      app.use(express.session({ secret: "appsession" }));
      app.use(express.errorHandler({showStack: true, dumpExceptions: true}));
      app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
      app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
});
```

Inside my `/public` directory I have 3 folders, css, js, and img.  Inside css I have a style.css.  When I try to access it directly via http://localhost:8001/public/css/style.css I get: `Cannot GET /public/css/style.css`

Any ideas what I could be doing wrong?

Thanks!

EDIT:

It seems to be related to how I have my routes setup.  I'm doing it like this:

```
     var routes = require('./routes')(db);
     pp.get('/', routes.index);
```

Then in my `index.js` file, I have:

```
module.exports = function(db) {
    return {

        index: function(req, res, next) { 
                res.render('index');
            }
         }
     }
```

I have my error handling enabled, but when I use the routing in this way, it doesn't use expresses error handling, however if I take this out, it does.

Answer (score 5):

You setup the static http middleware as follows:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

And retrieve a file in ./public/css/style.css with the url:

```
"/css/style.css"
```

public is not part of the path when you actually request the file.

Comment: Tried to access that  - same deal Cannot GET /css/style.css

Comment: is there anything in your console log when you try to access it?

Comment: check permissions on your files as well, but that is the way the express/connect static middleware works.  It handles subdirectories just fine.

Comment: Ah looks like it's a permissions error? When I do res.sendfile('../public/css/style.css'); I get 'Forbidden'

Answer (score 3):

Change your static handler to this:

```
app.use('/public/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
```

Then http://localhost:8001/public/css/style.css should get what you want

Full sample app that allows `curl http://localhost:8001/public/css/style.css`:

```
app.js
|-public
  |-css
    |-style.css

var express = require("express"),
    app = express.createServer();
app.use('/public/css', express.static(__dirname + '/public/css'));
app.listen(8001);
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot about the nested directory thing. Answer updated.

Comment: static handler does traverse sub-directories.

Comment: @BradHarris: Yeep, you're right. I couldn't get it working for a sec but it turns out I was being an idiot.

Answer (score 0):

Was running into the same issue found the answer here

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/298

When you have try to use nested files it kinda get lost,

it says fixed on the tracker a year ago, however i tried today and worked fine

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I have two services running on my host. Django is running the site at the root: http://myURL.com, and then Node is running at http://myURL.com/node

The configuration is fine with all the files in Node. The index.html file is requested fine, but the index.html when it requests the stylesheets and static files, the request gets caught by Django before it makes it to Node. Django saw the file and had no idea what it is and returned the 404 error.

By disabling Django from catching the requests to those files it all works fine.